# AAC write stream to file error

Tags: ios, core-audio, audiostreamer

I trying to record aac audio stream to file.

i creating a AudioFileID

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription asbd2;
    memset(&asbd2, 0, sizeof(asbd2));
    asbd2.mSampleRate = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] sampleRate];
    asbd2.mChannelsPerFrame = (UInt32)[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] inputNumberOfChannels];
AudioFileID audioFile;
    NSArray * dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString * docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *pathForTheFile = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.caf"];
    CFURLRef fileURL = (__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathForTheFile];
OSStatus status = AudioFileCreateWithURL(fileURL,
                                             kAudioFileAAC_ADTSType,
                                             &asbd2,
                                             kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile,
                                             &audioFile);
self.fileIDGlob = audioFile;
```

it creates without errors.

then i open a stream and parse it(works without errors). i use https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer to read stream

```
err = AudioFileStreamOpen(self, ASPropertyListenerProc, ASPacketsProc, 
                                    fileTypeHint, &audioFileStream);
AudioFileStreamParseBytes(audioFileStream, length, bytes, kAudioFileStreamParseFlag_Discontinuity);
```

When i trying to write data to file

```
OSStatus status = AudioFileWriteBytes(self.fileIDGlob, false, 0, &length, &bytes);
```

in status i receive 1869627199, as i understand it is kAudioFileOperationNotSupportedError.

But i can't understand why i receive this error code.

Comment: did you find the problem? thanks